# Run template conditionally on azure pipeline yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two different yml pipelines. I always trigger pipeline & send variable values via postman body. Here is the body portion.

```
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": 151
        },
        "parameters": "{\"Plan\":\"sand\"}"
}
```

Now i want to run a template with the condition that if the Plan is sand, then template will run. I have used many conditions but nothing is working. Providing some conditions that i tried,

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.Plan, 'sand') }}:
  - template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates

- ${{ if eq(parameters.Plan, 'sand') }}:
  - template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates

- template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates
  condition: eq(variables['Plan'], 'sand')

- template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates
  condition: eq(parameters['Plan'], 'sand')

- ${{ if eq(variables['Plan'], 'sand') }}:
  - template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates

- ${{ if eq(parameters['Plan'], 'sand') }}:
  - template: Sandbox Tasks/sand.yml@templates
```

What would be the proper way to run a template with conditions by matching a variables value?

Comment: the first one - ${{ if eq(variables.Plan, 'sand') }}: should work, does your template work at all with out condition? share the test of your yaml paramter, and steps if you can

Comment: Tried the first one. Pipeline runs without error but template steps are not visible even not skipped. Maybe it didn't match the value.

Comment: There I asked to share your parameters parts,

Comment: I have already shared my parameters list that i passed by json body with POST request with postman in question. Is there any requirement to add any kind of parameter/variable declearation?

Comment: Could you try to change the parameters to `"templateParameters": {"Plan":"sand"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_python, true)}}:
  - template: ../Python/install-python.yml 
    parameters:
        variable_group: '${{parameters.variable_group}}'
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_python, false)}}:
  - template: cdk-installation.yml
    parameters:
        variable_group: '${{parameters.variable_group}}'
```